# Transform app.config with Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing, xamarin

is there a way to apply transformations to the app.config file in Xamarin?

Basically I have a few tests that will run on Visual Studio and Xamarin. On Visual Studio I transform the app.config values using SlowCheetah, so I don't have to change them every time.

When I open the same project on Xamarin, it only reads the main app.config even having the Configurations for the others there. I believe slow cheetah is not compatible, but is there any other file transformation that can be used on Xamarin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way of doing it, I use some IF directives in a static class and go from there, and even that's not perfect with PCL's and device specific IF directives, see [In monodroid or monotouch what should I use instead of app.config for configuration strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703292/in-monodroid-or-monotouch-what-should-i-use-instead-of-app-config-for-configurat/13703831#13703831)